# Is there a way to show recommend Documents for the current logged-in user

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, modern-experience, document, sitepages

Inside our SharePoint online modern page >> we can add a News modern web part and define the source as the "Recommended for current user", as follow:

[image]

But can we do the same to show recommended Documents for the current user? using other web parts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no recommended documents web part in SharePoint Online.

However, there is "Recent documents" web part in SharePoint which shows the most recent documents accessed by the current user of the page.

**Documentation**: [Use the Recent documents web part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-recent-documents-web-part-8aa8c0f2-d2e3-43f9-90f5-fd6ddf0669c3)

Comment: but what is the criteria used to define that a document is recent to the login user? does it only depend on the created/modified date?

Comment: I believe those are the documents created/modified/opened recently by currently logged in user.

Comment: ok i see...thanks for the info. so those are not the recent documents added to the sites.. those are the recent documents accessed by the user? am i correct?

Comment: Yes, correct. If you want to show the site activity, you can use [Site activity](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-site-activity-web-part-1fa91401-ac36-42b6-beba-bb8469d6cbfa) web part (I don't think it matches fully with your requirements).

Answer (score 4):

SharePoint recommendations on modern pages help you and your users discover pages and news in your organization.

You may refer to the following link: [SharePoint Recommendations](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sharepoint-page-recommendations-12bf4c4e-3452-4575-afd4-ef7536b027fa)